# How do I set my menu as active?

Tags: android

I have this menu:

[image]

Which I created like so:

**menu_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.ZZZZ.global.YYYY.XXXX">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nearbyButton"
        android:title="Nearby"
        android:onClick="showNearbyPressed"
        android:state_selected="true"
    />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/browseAtoZButton"
        android:title="Browse A to Z"
        android:onClick="showAtoZPressed"
        android:state_selected="true"
    />

</menu>
```

And I place this in the activity XML like so:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/Navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#Ccc"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
/>
```

The problem is that if I click on "Browse A to Z", then the "Nearby" remains highlighted. " Browse A to Z" stays the same. What I was expecting was that the browse button will get the highlighted blue/purple color, and Nearby will become grey. But this does not happen.

1. How do I change this?
2. Is it perhaps a font thing and I have to manually change the font/color when you click on it?

I've tried:

```
navigation.performClick();
```

And:

```
navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nearbyButton);
```

Any ideas as to what I am missing here?

Comment: Why do you've `android:state_selected="true"` in both menus ?

Answer (score 0):

First, remove `android:state_selected="true"` from your menu items. Update your `menu_navigation.xml` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.ZZZZ.global.YYYY.XXXX">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nearbyButton"
        android:title="Nearby"
        android:onClick="showNearbyPressed" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/browseAtoZButton"
        android:title="Browse A to Z"
        android:onClick="showAtoZPressed" />

</menu>
```

**Handling items state**

You need to provide a `ColorStateList` resource, and set this resource as `background` for the `app:itemIconTint` and `app:itemTextColor` attributes:

**Update `BottomNavigationView` as below:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/Navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#Ccc"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"   
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/item_bg"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/item_bg" />
```

**Here is the `item_bg.xml`:**

```
<!-- item_bg.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/blue" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Hope this will help~